# Запуск скриптов по крону с разными версиями python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня возникли проблемы со скриптами. Скрипты запускаются из разных папок.

Скрипт А - запускается на версии python 3.5 , которая по умолчанию есть в Debian

Скрипт Б - требует версию 3.7 python.

Что нужно сделать, чтобы запустить Скрипт Б?
Установить дополнительную версию python?
Помануалить и как-то через Docker запустить
Или с помощью pyenv ?

Вообще я могу с помощью виртуального окружения в папку установить нужные мне версии python и уже запускать скрипт как надо?

Comment: Установите дополнительную версию python (и вообще обновите свой debian, в нём уже давно есть версия 3.7, а в testing даже 3.9)

Comment: @andreymal ну так это не выход, а вдруг мне понадобится в следующий раз еще какая то библиотека, которая уже не дружит со старой или наоборот с новой версией python/

Comment: установить нужную версию (дополнительно к той что уже имеется), создать с помощью неё `venv`, запускать скрипт кроном из окружения